# How to prepend numbers to typed values in column

Tags: microsoft-excel-2007

I need to manually enter a list of six-digit codes in a column. Each code starts with the same two-number prefix, `03`.

e.g.:

```
030144
030289
030283
```

Is there a way that I can type just the last four digits of the code but have the cell AND formula bar show the full six-digit code?

In other words, a custom number format will not do because the full six-digit code won't be displayed in the formula bar.

Answer (score 0):

To input all row of column A as 03 in text, and to input service number in column B in text too. 
The formula in column C will be either `=A1&B1` or `=CONCATENATE(A1,B1)`

For example:

> A     B       C
>
> 03    0001    =CONCATENATE(A1,B1)
>
> You will get 030001 in C1.

Comment: which means that i should have 2 extra columns, but i used format cells/custom, here it gives me what i want, but the only problem is the numbers ie 6 digits are not reflected in the address/formula bar, it only gives me either 1, 2, 201......etc but not 030001 etc.

Comment: Like I said, you need to apply the format to TEXT format but not digital format.

Comment: thanks.......but is it possible to use just one column with the above format/custom format and to display the 6 digits in the formula bar?

Comment: It depends. If you want to type the 4 digits in one cell manual and display the 6 digits result after typing, I dont see possibility unless to use VBA. My question is why not to use extra column? you can hide or delete them after your typing.

Comment: ok..........i will go for the 2 extra columns as u say.....thanks Hans.